# jQuery Validation doesn't fire if next input is non-blank

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've set up a simple fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/51uwoc5w/7/ that has two inputs, the first of which has validation rules (of required) applied to it.  Strange behaviors happen if the second input has any value.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" class='jquery-validate' method='post' action=''>
  <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="iGUI">GUI</label>
      <input type="text" id="iGUI1" class="form-control iGUI">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="iGUI2">GUI 2</label>
      <input type="text" id="iGUI2" class="form-control iGUI2">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Hooking up validation via:

var id = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {

```
    var validator = $('form.jquery-validate').validate({
        onsubmit: false,
        invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
            $("pre").prepend("\n" + (id++) + " invalidHandler.");
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            $("pre").prepend("\n" + (id++) + " errorPlacement " + element.attr("id"));
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $("pre").prepend("\n" + (id++) + " highlight " + element.id);
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $("pre").prepend("\n" + (id++) + " unhighlight " + element.id);
        }
    });

    $('.iGUI').rules('add', {
                required: true,
                messages: {
                    required: 'Global Unique Identifier is a required field.'
                } } );

});
```

Here are the four scenarios (of course non-working one was my preferred method of UI interaction/testing).  Success is defined by seeing a 'highlight' and 'errorPlacement' event.

Scenario 1 (works) - Both inputs blank, using mouse
1) Type value in first input
2) Click with mouse outside input
3) Click with mouse inside input
4) Clear input
5) Validation occurs (success)

Scenario 2 (works) - Both inputs blank, using keyboard (tab/shift+tab)
1) Type value in first input
2) Press TAB
3) Press SHIFT+TAB
4) Clear input
5) Validation occurs (success)

Scenario 3 (works) - Second input has value, using mouse
1) TAB to or click second input and type a value
2) SHIFT+TAB or click first input and type a value
3) Click with mouse outside input
4) Click with mouse inside input
4) Clear input
5) Validation occurs (success)

Scenario 4 (**fails**) - Second input has value, using keyboard
1) TAB to or click second input and type a value
2) SHIFT+TAB or click first input and type a value
3) Press TAB
4) Press SHIFT+TAB
5) Clear input
6) Validation **does not** occur (**failure**)

Answer (score 0):

> *Scenario 4 (fails) - Second input has value, using keyboard 1) TAB to or click second input and type a value 2) SHIFT+TAB or click first input and type a value 3) Press TAB 4) Press SHIFT+TAB 5) Clear input 6) Validation does not occur (failure)*

This is not a failure.  "Lazy" validation is the default.

This plugin will always ignore the `required` rules until the form is submitted the first time.  You can enter values, tab around, delete values, enter values again and the `required` rules will always be ignored until the `submit` is first clicked.

See [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-a-few-things-to-look-out-for-when-playing-around-with-the-demo):

> Before a field is marked as invalid, the **validation is lazy**: *Before submitting the form for the first time*, the user can tab through fields without getting annoying messages – they won't get bugged before having the chance to actually enter a correct value

---

To implement "Eager" validation...

```
onkeyup: function (element, event) {
    if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "") {
        return;
    } else {
        this.element(element);
    }
},
onfocusout: function(element) {
    this.element(element); 
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/zLh6bpsa/**

Comment: Not exactly same behavior.  As the same scenario works as long as *second* input doesn't have a value.  I've already been through the input 'once' as I entered value, so don't think this applies.

Comment: @Terry, of course this applies; your scenario #4 is the definition of "Lazy" validation.   In your scenario, the form has not been submitted yet, so no "required" validation is going to occur.   Read the documentation:  It says *"Before **submitting** the form for the first time"*, not "already been through the input once".

Comment: Ah I misread.  A few things however...3 of the 4 scenarios 'work' without having the form submitted...since it validates this 'same scenario' if you use a mouse (Scenario #3) versus a keyboard (Scenario #4), I'd expect both scenarios to behave the same...finally, a contributor on github repo said it has been fixed in latest (I don't have nodejs or grunt cli installed, so haven't been able to build my own *.js file and verify).

Comment: Thanks for sample.  I created a workaround too.  Something like:
     function jQueryValidateInput() {
        var input = $(this);
        var val = input.val();
        if (val == "") {
            input.valid();
        }
    }

    $('.iGUI').on("input", validateInput );.
    In yours, what does this.element(element);  do?  Just curious?

Comment: @Terry, `this.element(element)` forces immediate validation of `element`.  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element/

Comment: @Terry, Thanks for the info.  However, SO is not for bug reporting.  In other words, if you believe your OP to be seeking help with code you wrote, then you're in the right place.  Conversely, if you believe your OP to be a bug report about this plugin, then SO is not the right place.  Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, I don't see the developer acknowledging this as a bug yet in any of the linked GitHub threads.

Comment: I guess I double posted (bad form?) not thinking it was a 'bug/issue' in plugin, then he said "This is already addressed in #1579 and #1680. So, it should be fixed by now." to me implying it was a 'bug'.  Thanks for the help and SO advice.

Comment: @Sparky see https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/1508 for the description of the issue, but it's not labeled as a Bug by the owner (even though it was a bug IMHO).

Comment: Also, "Addressing an issue" means that it could be an issue, an improvement (docs, ...), a feature request or a bug.